# calling onTouch method for an item who's layout is created on touch of another item

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have an activity that uses a custom grid view (and an adapter) to list cards. I also have a common custom menu layout that is created/shown on the grid view's item onTouch method. For each item in the custom menu I again have a touch listener and I would like to do some action on release on the menu item.

This may sound confusing so let me explain what I am trying to achieve. In my main activity:

1. I would like to display a list of `products` that I fetch from my websrever via a `JSON` api
2. For each item that is displayed I want to implement an `ontouchlistener`, that on touch will show the menu that 3 items.

   - Like Button
   - Buy Button
   - Share Button
3. On the same touch, if the touch is moved over a menu item and then released I would like to perform certain action.

### Where I am right now ?

Currently I have implemented the above and the menu is shown with the items when I touch a list item. But when I move the touch over to item and release nothing happens.

So the `onTouch` method for the menu item is never triggered. From what I understand this must be happening as the menu layout is created on the touch event of the product item.

The above `onTouch` method is invoked if I use another finger (while I am still holding the previous touch) and specifically touch the menu item.

Following is the code I have

#### MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize the cardMenu
    // This is the menu that will be displayed
    // on the touch method of each product item
    CardMenu cardMenu = (CardMenu) overlayView.findViewById(R.id.card_menu);

    final int menuItemLength = CARD_MENU_ITEMS.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < menuItemLength; i++) {
        ImageView item = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        item.setImageResource(CARD_MENU_ITEMS[i]);

        cardMenu.addItem(item, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("DEBUG::", "Card Menu Item Clicked");
            }
        }, new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    // Implement Grid view
    adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_list_item, productList, this);
    gridView = (StaggeredGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Add click and scroll listeners to the view
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    gridView.setOnScrollListener(this);

    // Load the trending product data into the productList
    getTrendingData();
}
```

#### ProductAdapter.java

```
RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener onImageTouch = new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v == null) { return false; }
        boolean defaultResult = v.onTouchEvent(event);

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int currentX = (int) event.getX();
            int currentY = (int) event.getY();
            DisplayMetrics metrics = activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;

            touchX = currentX;
            touchY = currentY;
            touchedView = v;
            // This shows the menu on the item card
            showCardMenu(v, currentX, currentY);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return false;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            hideCardMenu(); // This hides the car menu
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }
};
```

#### CardMenu.java

```
public void addItem(View item, OnClickListener listener, OnTouchListener touchListener) {
    cardMenuLayout.addView(item);
    item.setOnClickListener(getItemClickListener(listener));
    item.setOnTouchListener(getItemTouchListener(touchListener));
}

private OnClickListener getItemClickListener(final OnClickListener listener) {
    return new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View viewClicked) {
            Log.d("DEBUG::", "CARD MENU CHILD CLICKED");
        }
    };
}

private OnTouchListener getItemTouchListener(final OnTouchListener listener) {
    return new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (v == null) {return false;}
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.d("DEBUG::", "ACTION DOWN=======");
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                Log.d("DEBUG::", "ACTION MOVE=======");
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.d("DEBUG::", "ACTION UP=======");
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

So the flow I am looking to achieve is:

- A user touches a product item
- The menu is shown

  - While still holding the touch user moves his finger over one of the menu items and releases to take action
- User releases the touch
- The menu item is hidden

Comment: I still didnt check your code but i read what are you trying to achieve. So i would suggest you show that menu as default because from the `User Experience`, if the item is on top or bottom of the screen, to drag finger to the menu, while touching screen, can be very annoying

Comment: @hrskrs Thank you for your input. But changing designs and flows is not something that I can take a call on. To make my question/flow more clear I would suggest you look at the `button menu` used in the `pinterest`'s android app which does not seem like a bad UX at all. I am trying to achieve similar functionality.

Comment: yeah, you are right if the menu wont be static but based on the touch. `pinterest` is the best example of playing with such an idea

Comment: @hrskrs Exactly. The menu that I have implemented is not static but the layout is drawn around the touch coordinates. But the issue I am facing is how can pass the touch event that has been initiated before the menu was drawn to the onTouch of item inside the menu.

Comment: So the menu items are listening to the touchEvents initiated after the menu is drawn but do not recognize the already initiated touch event on which the menu was created.

Comment: try dispatchTouchEvent

Comment: @pskink Do you mean `dispatchTouchEvent` instead of `onTouch` in the product adapter ?

Comment: call cardMenu.dispatchTouchEvent inside onImageTouch

Comment: @pskink ok, I did call the `cardMenu.dispatchTouchEvent` and passed in the MotionEvent object to it but I want the event inside the `onTouchListener` of an `item` view which is a child of the `CardMenu`.